Ag-Grid data overlapping for a second on quick search
When I am doing quick search on grid the cellRenderer and data are overlapping each other for a second before readjusting.
enter image description here
When I am doing quick search on grid the cellRenderer and data are overlapping each other for a second before readjusting.
